# How to make document tabs in Visual Studio 2008 appear in left-to-right order, just as it was in earlier VS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In earlier versions of VS (2003 for sure, maybe 2005) when you open a project file, the tab opens to the right. In current VS 2008 it always opens to the left, so I have to rearrange them manually. It's time consuming and stupid, since I feel I'm forced to write in the right-to-the-left order. I looked for appropriate settings, but haven;t found anything.

Is this behaviour permanent? Any way to turn it back?

Comment: Which tabs are you talking about? VS keeps all tabs in the order and places you left them at the time of closing.

Comment: In the workspace when you double-click in solution or class explorer files are opened in new tabs. The tabs for these just opened files always jump in at the leftmost or rightmost position. The question is about how to change the current "leftmost" behaviour back to "rightmost" which was before.

Comment: Indeed, this is awful. A pity there is no option to change it. Every other IDE/editor I used opened tabs to the right.

Comment: Yes, this is really annoying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change to the side on which document tabs open was made in Visual Studio 2005. In 2003, new tabs opened on the right. In 2005 and later, new tabs open on the left. Personally, I dislike this behavior, but I've gotten used to it after a few years.

Unfortunately, this behavior is permanent and there isn't a setting to restore it.

Comment: Actually, exactly the opposite. In 2003 new tabs open on the right, in 2008 - to the left. Sadly since it is a huge productivity drop for me.

Comment: @so-sucks: Thanks for the catch. I mixed them up when I wrote the answer.

Answer (score 28):

In Visual Studio 2010, it is possible to have document tabs open left to right. The option is under: Tools > Environment > Documents

Check "Insert documents to the right of existing tabs"

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150107111248/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/zainnab/archive/2010/02/10/insert-documents-to-the-right-of-existing-tabs-vstipenv0001.aspx)

[image]

Comment: In VS2012 it is in Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs and Windows

Answer (score 1):

Commercial [Tabs Studio add-in](http://www.tabsstudio.com) for Visual Studio opens new tab on the right by default and generally allows lots of tab customization.

Answer (score 0):

You could try deleting \Visual Studio 2008\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings (well, backing it up) and rearranging your windows and quitting again -- this is the file where your personal preferences are saved, and it could be possible that it has become corrupted somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting that this tabs feature makes me dislike Visual Studio **every** time I use it.

1) It does not open a new document on the right (but on the left instead)

2) Ctrl+Tab is not going to the next tab. (but to the previously used tab instead)

Pretty good score.

No way to change this. Guess I am stupid for not getting used to this.

Comment: @Mark Ctrl+Tab is closer to Alt+Tab in Windows which shows windows in the order they were last accessed.  Also, if you want to move 1 tab left/right it is very easy to find your current tab and select the one to either side.  Most often, when coding, I find that I need to go back and forth quickly between tabs which are not close to each other.  As a result I find Visual Studio's implementation of Ctrl+Tab to make much more sense and to be easier to use.